# Replace varied but patterned text on website

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm trying to modify a website using Greasemonkey and javascript. I've found and modified a script that replaces the text I want to, but I'm using regex to remove all the text before "x" which means the script has to work on a certain div class only, not the whole page. I'm not even sure this is the right way to go about this so I figured I'd just start fresh and ask what's the best way to do it.

Example given in outer HTML. I'm looking to modify the inner HTML using the div class as an identifier:

```
<div class="sub">This line always begins with a number | 10 minutes ago by test</div>
```

Goal:

```
<div class="sub">10 minutes ago</div>
```

The pattern in the example is always the same. I'm looking to remove everything before and including "| " and everything after and including " by". The site includes about 50 of these lines so the solution would have to iterate through the whole page. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Tried:

I added this script to Greasemonkey. It works as intended but I'm not able to isolate it to a specific div which means it runs across the whole site, applying my replacement text to everything before the search result:

```
(function() {
var replacements, regex, key, textnodes, node, s; 

replacements = { 

"/^[^|]*|/": "123123123",
};

regex = {}; 
for (key in replacements) { 
regex[key] = new RegExp(key, 'g'); 
} 

textnodes = document.evaluate( "//body/text()", document, null,     XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null); 

for (var i = 0; i < textnodes.snapshotLength; i++) { 
node = textnodes.snapshotItem(i); 
s = node.data; 
for (key in replacements) { 
    s = s.replace(regex[key], replacements[key]); 
} 
node.data = s; 
} 

})();
```

Comment: This seems like it should be satisfied with a fairly straightforward `forEach()`, and updating `textContent` with a match: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9sjmx3aL/)? Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The script you provided produces this output: "1111 text | 20 minutes ago"
    
I'm trying to modify the regex to also remove the "1111 text |" part, but it's not really my language and I'm not sure it can be done in the same formula or if I need two separate ones.

Comment: Got it to work. The regex might not be pretty but it does exactly what it's supposed to. Huge thanks for the script that was a lot prettier than my original one, David!      
    
   `document.querySelectorAll('.sub').forEach(
    (el) => {
    let found = el.textContent.match(/([0-9.+]{0,16} (minutes|hours|days) ago)/);
    el.textContent = found ? found[0] : el.textContent
    });`

Comment: Nice! Please do consider posting that as an answer, we absolutely support, and encourage, self-answers; and it may well be useful for others in future. The output you mentioned is unexpected, but if you could post some of your “input” strings/code, and the outputs that might help illuminate your answer and it might show where I went wrong with my suggestion.

Comment: Well, the problem with not knowing what you're doing is that you still don't even when you manage to solve it, but I'll try to provide some ideas. I was somewhat incorrect when asking the question as the string I was working with, the one in the .sub class, in some cases looked like this "2017 6.1 blablabla | 30 minutes ago by test" and in other cases like this "30 minutes ago by test".

Comment: The "\d" in the regex you provided would start matching at "2017" in the first case, and "30" in the second one, and I needed it to start at "30" in both cases. The character "|" is also not present in the second case which is why it wouldn't work using that as a delimiter. I'm assuming the "{0,16}" in my regex works as a limit for how many characters/numbers before the word "days" it's allowed to match. I just tried it with "{0,5}" and that seemed to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer to the question:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.sub').forEach(
(el) => {
let found = el.textContent.match(/([0-9.+]{0,16} (seconds|minutes|hours|days) ago)/);
el.textContent = found ? found[0] : el.textContent
});
```

I'm not quite sure why this regex works but it matches and isolates for example "45 minutes ago", "6 hours ago" and "3 days ago" in strings that begins with a number which I do not wish to match, e.g "2017 6.1 blablabla | 30 minutes ago by test".